# How to implement Drop to mitigate StackOverflow for a merged Singly LinkedList and BinaryTree structure

Tags: rust, drop

My Linked structure is as follows:

```rs
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Value {
    Chain(Chain),
    Invalidate,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Chain {
    Link(Rc<Link>),
    Cons(Rc<Cons>),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Link {
    next: Value,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Cons {
    left: Value,
    right: Value,
}

impl Value {
    fn link(next: Value) -> Value {
        Value::Chain(Chain::Link(Rc::new(Link { next })))
    }

    fn cons(left: Value, right: Value) -> Value {
        Value::Chain(Chain::Cons(Rc::new(Cons { left, right })))
    }

    fn take(&mut self) -> Value {
        std::mem::replace(self, Value::Invalidate)
    }

    fn get_mut_link(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Link> {
        match self {
            Value::Chain(chain) => chain.get_mut_link(),
            _ => None,
        }
    }

    fn get_mut_cons(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Cons> {
        match self {
            Value::Chain(chain) => chain.get_mut_cons(),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

impl Chain {
    fn get_mut_link(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Link> {
        match self {
            Chain::Link(link) => Rc::get_mut(link),
            _ => None,
        }
    }

    fn get_mut_cons(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Cons> {
        match self {
            Chain::Cons(cons) => Rc::get_mut(cons),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

// impl

impl Drop for Value {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("NEW CALL");
        let mut stack = vec![self.take()];

        while let Some(mut value) = stack.pop() {
            {
                println!("STACK {}", stack.len());
                // println!("BEFORE {:?}", value);
                if let Some(link) = value.get_mut_link() {
                    stack.push(link.next.take());
                }

                if let Some(cons) = value.get_mut_cons() {
                    stack.push(cons.left.take());
                    stack.push(cons.right.take());
                }
                // println!("AFTER {:?}", value);
                println!("STACK {}", stack.len());
            }
        }

        println!("{:?}", self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut aaax = Value::cons(
        Value::cons(
            Value::cons(Value::Invalidate, Value::Invalidate),
            Value::cons(Value::Invalidate, Value::Invalidate),
        ),
        Value::cons(
            Value::cons(Value::Invalidate, Value::Invalidate),
            Value::cons(Value::Invalidate, Value::Invalidate),
        ),
    );

    for _ in 1..100000 {
        aaax = Value::link(aaax);
        aaax = Value::cons(aaax, Value::Invalidate);
    }
}
```

I know how to implement the `Drop` trait independently for each separate instance, i.e. if `Value` was `Link/Invalidate` or `Cons/Invalidate`

- `Link/Invalidate` is an iterative traversal where I can override the current `Link` before proceeding to the next
- `Cons/Invalidate` requires stitching together some trees

Trying to merge both of the approaches results in a mess of problems, trying to `match` between the two different `Link`s results in `X moved` errors.

I currently have stitched a generic approach using the following:

```
struct Link {
  children: Vec<Value>
}
```

which resolves the issue by simplification, but I don't want to go through this approach since I will *only* have 1 *or* 2 children.

Comment: Try reading [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/). They even have [a chapter specifically about drop](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/first-drop.html).

Comment: Yes, that's what I have read. I understand how to merge the two drop approaches, but actually implementing the drop is much more butchered than what it took to do it for a single drop approach.

That would be case of `Link/Invalidate` and with a bit of tweaking is what I have for the `Vec` child approach.

Comment: I guess one approach is artificially simplifying back to one type, by forcibly converting `Link` to a `Cons` just for dropping. Still looking for other suggestions but I think that should be barely clean enough for my tastes I guess, since the enum allocates the same amount of memory regardless of `Link` or `Cons`

Comment: Please provide your failing attempt so we can understand your problem better, otherwise the whole chapter on the problem seems to sufficiently describe the problem.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=70a8aa6157d9dbb91d8c2f871c457467

Comment: Please provide your failing attempts _in the question_, not as links to external resources.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was generating a new instance of `Value` when initializing the stack.

The logic of the iteration is correct, but because it was a new instance, when it went out of scope, it called `drop` again instead of iterating.

```
impl Drop for Value {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        use std::mem::replace;

        let mut stack = vec![];
        if let Value::Chain(ref mut chain) = self {
            if let Chain::Link(ref mut link) = chain {
                if let Some(link) = Rc::get_mut(link) {
                    stack.push(replace(&mut link.next, Value::Invalidate));
                }
            }

            if let Chain::Cons(ref mut cons) = chain {
                if let Some(ref mut cons) = Rc::get_mut(cons) {
                    stack.push(replace(&mut cons.left, Value::Invalidate));
                    stack.push(replace(&mut cons.right, Value::Invalidate));
                }
            }
        }

        while let Some(mut value) = stack.pop() {
            if let Value::Chain(ref mut chain) = value {
                if let Chain::Link(ref mut link) = chain {
                    if let Some(link) = Rc::get_mut(link) {
                        stack.push(replace(&mut link.next, Value::Invalidate));
                    }
                }

                if let Chain::Cons(ref mut cons) = chain {
                    if let Some(ref mut cons) = Rc::get_mut(cons) {
                        stack.push(replace(&mut cons.left, Value::Invalidate));
                        stack.push(replace(&mut cons.right, Value::Invalidate));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```